# Battery Charger... Some Questions

Tags: battery-charging

I have built a battery charger found it on this [site](http://www.extremecircuits.net/2010/06/simple-nicd-battery-charger_24.html).

[image]

but I have some questions about it.

R2 = 390 Ohm
R1 = 120 Ohm
R3 = 3.3 Ohm

Source is 12 V DC

The rest as indicated in schematic.

My first question is: is this a good and reliable battery charger?

In fact I have built it and tried to charge a NiMh 170 mAh @ 7.2 V battery! but it got hot so I disconnected it immediately; I measured the voltage using AVO meter and it showed 8.2 V or so!
I just plugged it in for a minute or two! Could it be charged in this very short of time?

Second: would you please explain each part what does it do? I am really confused about that! And how the values of resistors have been chosen? The description in that site is complicated.

Third: Does this circuit stop charging when battery is fully charged? If not, can you give me a slight idea about that thing.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Well I didn't down-vote, but I see some reasons why some people would. Fist, you show us a circuit and don't provide a link to the text that goes with the circuit. Next, you show that you have no idea what the circuit is actually doing. Next, you provide no information about the circuit YOU made. As the results of those actions we first have to figure out what exactly the circuit is doing without knowing what the author expected the circuit to do.

Comment: After that, if the schematic doesn't have any major issues with it, we have to make a list of the things that could have possibly gone wrong with your assembly of the circuit and post them hoping that it's one of the things from the list. Some members may feel that this is too much work and will give negative and close votes. What you can do to improve the situation is to post a direct link to the location you got the circuit from (it's a lot of work to go through all the schematics on battery chargers at the linked site).

Comment: The second thing you could do is to post a nice, not too large, focused, clear and sharp photo of what you actually made showing all components and marking the connection points (Many people post blurry and out of focus photos. They do not help). This will make it easier for us to see if there's a problem with the assembly of the circuit itself or operation of the circuit. If you have appropriate equipment, it may be a good idea to post all the voltages in the circuit, just in case some part is misbehaving.

Comment: So the main problem here is that you have to make the question attractive enough for us to help you with it. Also about Elektor: That is an electronics magazine that often publishes circuit schematics. Some members feel that the circuit schematic was directly copied from that magazine. I do not see how that has any impact on the question though.

Comment: @Andrejako Thank you very very much... only for your kindness and comity!!! Secondly... Thank you soooo much for your help... I will take the mentioned points into account, and I hope you help me with this!

Comment: The purpose of moderation is to promote good questions. Your question lacked references and you didn't seem to attempt to figure out how the circuit worked before posting. If you edit your question and fix some of the issues with it, it should attract some upvotes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the descriptions of what each part does:

First D1: It's there to provide protection from revere polarity of the power supply. Diodes usually conduct current only in one direction and if the power supply is incorrectly connected, the diode will prevent it from damaging the charger.

Next is the input capacitor C1. Basically as the current consumption of the device changes, it takes time for those changes to propagate to the power supply and for power supply to respond to them (this goes the other way too! The power supply may provide lower voltage for a short amount of time that will disturb the charger). Once C1 is charged, electric charge for any sudden changes in consumption will be drained from it and will provide some electricity for the charger for those brief periods.

C2 and C3 are there to prevent the LM317 from oscillating and need to be physically very close to the regulator. They work similar to C1, but they stabilize a bit the voltage on the the adjust pin of the regulator.

After that we have R1, R2, R3, R4, T1 and D2. They adjust the output of the regulator. Basically LM317 tries to adjust its output voltage so that voltage on its adjust pin is 1.25 V. For a fixed voltage, usually two resistors are used to set it. One often called in the datasheet for the part  R1 and the second called R2.  R1 is connected to the output pin of the regulator and the adjust pin and R2 is connected to the adjust pin and the circuit ground (or common). In out case, R2 is datasheet's R1 and the transistor and related parts take the place of datasheet's R2.

So our R2 is a fixed resistor and we need to have changing voltage for the proper battery charge. The transistor is there for that. Basically the current going through our R4 resistor affects how much current goes through the transistor.

I'm a bit too tired to provide an actual calculation now, so I'll leave that for someone else, but if there's some trouble with the circuit, it's most likely to be with transistor and the way it's used.